How can I make my ScrollView both horizontally and vertically scrollable?
I have a React Native Expo application with the navigation template.
I can't make the ScrollView scrollable horizontally and vertically. I'm creating a workplace reservation hobby project where the user can book his workplace. I'm using Svg components for this (and react-native-svg). I created 10 dummy desks and added 1600px height, 1200px width for the Svg component. I'm able to scroll horizontally but I can't scroll vertically. When I'm changing the ScrollView back to View then I'm able to scroll vertically but (obviously) not horizontally. What could be the problem?
OfficeSvgBooking.tsx:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Svg, { Rect, Text } from "react-native-svg";
import { View } from "./Themed";

export default function OfficeSvgBooking() {
  const [selectedDesks, setSelectedDesks] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const toggleDesk = (deskId: string) => {
    setSelectedDesks((prev) =>
      prev.includes(deskId)
        ? prev.filter((id) => id !== deskId)
        : [...prev, deskId]
    );
  };

  const desks = [
    { id: "desk1", x: 50, y: 50, isRotated: false },
    { id: "desk2", x: 150, y: 50, isRotated: true },
    { id: "desk3", x: 250, y: 150, isRotated: false },
    { id: "desk4", x: 350, y: 250, isRotated: true },
    { id: "desk5", x: 450, y: 350, isRotated: false },
    { id: "desk6", x: 550, y: 450, isRotated: true },
    { id: "desk7", x: 650, y: 550, isRotated: false },
    { id: "desk8", x: 750, y: 650, isRotated: true },
    { id: "desk9", x: 850, y: 750, isRotated: false },
    { id: "desk10", x: 950, y: 850, isRotated: true },
  ];

  return (
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}
      style={styles.scrollView}
      horizontal={true}
      directionalLockEnabled={false}
    >
      <Svg height="1600" width="1200">
        <Rect x="0" y="0" width="1200" height="1600" fill="lightgray" />
        {desks.map((desk) => (
          <React.Fragment key={desk.id}>
            <Rect
              x={desk.x}
              y={desk.y}
              width={desk.isRotated ? "80" : "40"}
              height={desk.isRotated ? "40" : "80"}
              fill={selectedDesks.includes(desk.id) ? "green" : "red"}
              onPress={() => toggleDesk(desk.id)}
            />
            <Text
              x={desk.isRotated ? desk.x + 40 : desk.x + 20}
              y={desk.isRotated ? desk.y + 25 : desk.y + 45}
              fontSize="12"
              fill="white"
              textAnchor="middle"
              onPress={() => toggleDesk(desk.id)}
            >
              {desk.id}
            </Text>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </Svg>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    width: 1200,
    height: 1600,
  },
});

two.tsx:
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { View } from '@/components/Themed';
import OfficeSvgBooking from '@/components/thirdFloor';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <OfficeSvgBooking />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


i tested you code (OfficeSvgBooking.tsx) and it works properly (horizontally+ vertically)
which kind of versions do you use for (React native & svg )

react-native: 0.76.3
react-native-svg: 15.8.0
expo: 52.0.11
It is strange because I created another approach on a different page and there I can scroll both vertically and horizontally. I inserted the png of the floor plan and created the desks on that. I don't know what could be the problem with this one.
